# Not receiving email with exported data

Tags: parse-platform

I'm not receiving any email from parse when I try to export data.

I export data, got message that data have been exported successfully, but never received email with data.

Any idea what can I do?

Comment: why -1, where can I get this answer if it's parse community? I cannot find a way to receive email, and this is directly related with parse system .

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the correct email address for it?, Also make sure you check your junk folder.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your app/program. If anything, it's your email or the parse servers that are causing the problem.